# Return http response to be rendered in page asp.mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I would like to call a post request that would return an http response that should be rendered by the browser. My attempt led to the browser displaying text value `system.web.httpwebresponse`

```
var webrequest = WebRequest.Create("URL");
webrequest.Method = "POST";
string postData = "test=1&test2=2";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webrequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
Uri newUri = new Uri("http://proxy");
// Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
myProxy.Address = newUri;
// Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
webrequest.Proxy = myProxy;
var resp = webrequest.GetResponse();
return resp;
```

Comment: you could return the stream...

Comment: can you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the stream as a `File` response.

```
return File(resp.GetResponseStream(), resp.ContentType);
```

Comment: it was successful, but it renderd the html without related images and styles

Comment: @MarwanTushyeh you will have to proxy those too

Answer (score 1):

if your result is text, then you could

```
return Content(new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), resp.ContentType)
```